# Vba Code for the folder & subfolder list in a parent folder

Tags: vba, directory, subdirectory

I am creating a code in which if i click on a button then all the folders & subfolders in a folder will be listed. Like I have a folder name "parent". There is 5 folders under the parent folder. suppose a, b, c, d, e. Again there is more than one folder in each a, b, c, d, e folder. Now I want the code to list all the folders in a click. Here is the code.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

'Factory List--------------------------------------------

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B100").ClearContents

Dim FactoryFolderName As String
Dim FactoryFolderPath As String

FactoryFolderPath = "C:\Users\Rokon\Desktop\Project Test Folder\Sub-Contract\"
FactoryFolderName = Dir(FactoryFolderPath, vbDirectory)

Do While FactoryFolderName <> ""
If GetAttr(FactoryFolderPath & FactoryFolderName) = vbDirectory And FactoryFolderName <> "." And FactoryFolderName <> ".." Then
    
Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Value = FactoryFolderName: Exit For
        Next cell
        '---------------------------------------------------
        Dim BuyerFolderName As String
        Dim BuyerFolderPath As String
        
        BuyerFolderPath = FactoryFolderPath & FactoryFolderName & "\"
        BuyerFolderName = Dir(BuyerFolderPath, vbDirectory)
        
        Do While BuyerFolderName <> ""
        If GetAttr(BuyerFolderPath & BuyerFolderName) = vbDirectory And BuyerFolderName <> "." And BuyerFolderName <> ".." Then
    
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Cells
            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Value = BuyerFolderName: Exit For
        Next cell
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
        End If
        BuyerFolderName = Dir()
        Loop
        '-----------------------------------------------------
    
Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

FactoryFolderName = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

But the problem is this code is throwing an error at the `FactoryFolderName = Dir()` line. Pls help!

Comment: It is not allowed to use another `Dir` (`BuyerFolderName = Dir(BuyerFolderPath, vbDirectory)` after the first one (inside the first loop). In such a case the first iteration is killed and it will behave like in your case... You should try the VBScript way do do what you need.

Comment: Suggest you look into File System Object. You can loop the folders recursively to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks both of you boss. It worked with File System Object(FSO).